# Make a C++ Program Run without a Window Using gcc/g++?

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, g++

I have a program that is very simple; it plays a single audio file defined by a path on loop forever until the program is terminated. Code here:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    PlaySound("C:\\Users\\Ben\\Desktop\\silence.wav", NULL, SND_LOOP | SND_ASYNC | SND_FILENAME);
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

The program itself runs fine, but as you would expect, it generates a blank console window, like any program would. But since I want to have this program running in the background and not be visible, is it possible that I could write it so that it doesn't have a window at all? I realize that if I did this the only way out would be to end it from process manager, but that's fine. Also, I want to do this in code only/from the g++ compiler; I tried reading up on doing this with Visual Studio, but I could never get it to work, and it also seems really unnecessary for something of this scale. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: It is NOT a duplicate — OP specifically states: "is it possible .. that it doesn't have a window at all?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```c
int main()
{
  FreeConsole();
  PlaySound(...);
  ...
}
```

This kind of program can only be killed from the task manager. You might want to consider setting some sort of IPC so that you can instruct an existing instance to turn off the sound and quit.

Comment: When I do this, the window just shows up briefly and then disappears. I checked Task Manager, and the process isn't running. I didn't make any modifications to my code except that. Additionally, I tried the link above that this question was marked as a duplicate of, but that doesn't work for me; it builds, but when I run it nothing happens, and again, I don't see it in the Task Manager.

Comment: `cin.get()` won't work if you don't have a console.  Try `Sleep(INFINITE);` instead.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for pointing that out. I'm gonna mark this as the answer then, although I won't test it until tomorrow.

Comment: If you use `Sleep(INFINITE)` then the only way to kill your program will ever be through the Task Manager.

Comment: @Dúthomhas that's exactly what I want. It should be like a Windows service or something similar.

Comment: Quick note: I just got to testing, and indeed cin.get() was the problem, pretty silly oversight on my part. I'm okay with this being closed, since both answers now work since I've replaced it with sleep(INFINITE). Thanks for the help.